# Mongo Explorer in IntelliJ doesn't show collection

Tags: mongodb, intellij-idea

I have installed the Mongo explorer in IntelliJ, it doesn't show my collection (only admin, config and local)

- Proxy Settings are ok
- Path to mongo shell: test successful

...am I missing something here?

- IntelliJ 18.2
- Mongo Plugin 0.12.0
- Win 10 Enterprise

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was not authenticated with a user that had the privilege to see other tables.

Make sure to not only connect to the database server but also authenticate yourself.